# Migrating data from parse.com to MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, migration

I was trying to migrate my app from parse.com to my own server.
After configuring parse server on AWS and mongodb on Mlab , I tried to migrate data using parse.com dashboard , however after clicking the migrate button , it show me this error "The destination database was not empty." even though my mongo database is empty ?